# Move directory contents based off findstr

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Using windows 10 and I would like to recursively go through my movies folder and move any movies that have the genre Documentary written in it's associated nfo file.  My directory structure is:

```
D:\Movie1
  -Movie1.ext
  -Movie.nfo
  -Extrafanart\
D:\Movie2
  -Movie2.ext
  -Movie.nfo
  -Extrafanart\
```

So, I want to search "movie.nfo" that will be located within each directory.  If it has documentary genre, then I want to move that entire directory to a new location.  The following I was able to get to work, but I'm only able to move the nfo file, not the directories' contents.  I've been trying to work it out, but I can't figure it out:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('findstr /i /s /m "<genre>Documentary</genre>" "D:\*.nfo"') do move "%%I" "E:\Documentaries\"
```

-EDIT-

So I have attempted to use powershell and I'm able to achieve the same thing, only moving the nfo, still can't move nfo's directory and contents:

```
get-childitem F:\Downloads\Movies\ -filter Movie.nfo -recurse | select-string -list -pattern "<genre>Documentary</genre>" | move -dest E:\Documentaries\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my version of the solution:

```
@ ECHO off

PUSHD %~dp0

CLS
CD Movies
FOR /D /r %%G IN ("*") DO (
    findstr /C:"<genre>Documentary</genre>" "%%~G\*.nfo" >nul && (
        ECHO "%%~G" is a Documentary!
        MOVE "%%~G" C:\Documentaries
    ) || (
        ECHO "%%~G" is NOT a Documentary!
    )
)

CD ..

POPD
```

You may suppress the output of `MOVE` command as well like this:

```
MOVE "%%~G" C:\Documentaries >nul
```

Comment: As movie names tend to have spaces you should double quote all references conatining `%%G` and the OP used the wildcard in`*.nfo` so not all .nfo seem to benamed  Movie.nfo.

Comment: I changed move to xcopy and your code does exactly what my question already does, only moves the nfo file.  I want to INCLUDE the directory and ANY other files located in the directory.

Comment: @Failstyle: Did you run my code? I've tested it on `Windows 7` (I don't have Windows 10) and it `move`s the whole directory to `Documentaries`.

Comment: Running your code as is, gives me access denied when it attempts to move the files.  If I run it as admin, it jumps to my system32 folder.  If I change move to xcopy, it only copys the nfo file.  I have all necessary admin rights as well as running cmd as admin.  I would assume it has to do with windows vers.

Comment: @Failstyle: I've updated the code for taking care of the `system32` issue. Check `PUSHD` and `POPD` in the answer. You can now `Run as Admin` and verify. It should work now.

Comment: Running the updated script normally or as admin returns access denied when attempting to move the files.  Changed move to xcopy and it's producing the same results, only copies nfo file.  I would say it's a difference in cmd.exe version

Comment: @Failstyle: Alas! Yeah, it sure looks like it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort though, VERY APPRECIATED!

Comment: @Failstyle: You are very welcome! :) BTW, I've just tested it on `Windows 10` (just found one as VM) and it worked there too. It didn't even ask for Admin privileges. I've tried it on C drive with `Movies`, `Documentaries` and `list.bat`. There might be something else (policies, privileges, etc.) that you need to check on your machine.

Comment: I figured what the hell and made folders on my C: drive and your code works absolutely perfect.  Very weird that it doesn't work on my D or F drive....I'll check privileges and policies, thanks for the heads up!  Marking as answer.

Comment: @Failstyle: I'm glad I could help! :)